# How do i make a GET requests from Imgur's API via Axios on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, imgur

I've tried everything,it keeps returning an error message

```
main.js?attr=_BODkjRO5QpCpDBDHmq3zW7ER-QQAJ8TUaG_zfoS-_UYoHvVr1lIpJQyTDNBAEyN:2605 GET https://api.imgur.com/3/image?query=cars 400
```

and

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

It works with their GET gallery URL though, so I don't understand if the GET Image URL is broken.

My code:

```
const response = await axios.get( 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image' , {
  params: {query: text},
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Client-ID {MY ACTUAL CLIENT ID}'
  }
})

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the api is like

```
https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{imageID}
```

and not

```
https://api.imgur.com/3/image?query=cars
```

maybe you are looking for something like this? https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#gallery-search

Comment: This is useful! I'm actually trying to get images from their websites API and display on my app using a search query but it seems as though they don't make such a GET request provision. I may end up using Unsplash

Comment: did you try sending the request to the endpoint https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search?q={searchTerm} ?

Comment: This worked! thanks, Their API documentation is the worst I've ever read

Comment: you're welcome, yeah the documentation is messy a little bit :D